# How can I use the output of a wireless mic reciever as a wireless monitor and get audio on both sides of my headphones?

Tags: stereo, headphones, live, monitoring, mono

I referred to this Q&A, but I'm still confused:
[Stereo and mono cables and jacks? What happens when you cross them?](https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/25577/stereo-and-mono-cables-and-jacks-what-happens-when-you-cross-them)

I have this wireless lav set:
[http://www.amazon.com/Sennheiser-EW-112P-G3-A-omni-directional/dp/B002CWQTXG/ref=pd_sxp_grid_pt_0_2](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B002CWQTXG)

I'm wanting to use the transmitter to transmit an aux from a mixing console and use the receiver to plug my headphones into. I want the mono signal to go to both sides of my headphones (plugging stereo plug into mono jack).

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 4):

You have a few options,

1) you can buy a 1/8 or 1/4 inch headphone jack and short the L R connections together since (in an unbalanced situation (most regular headphones)) they share a common ground. Keep in mind you will be driving twice the load from the same source which will effect the output.

2) You can buy a headphone amplifier that has a mono input function. Just look around they are out there. If you are talking about the signal from line out of the receiver you will need a headphone amp anyway.

3) You can try and sell/trade the system for a wireless monitoring system designed for this task.

Answer (score 1):

Sennheiser actually has a G3 receiver with a monitor output. That model is generally what we would use if we wanted to do a wireless monitoring feed. Barr that model, you will have to use a 1/8 mono male to 1/8 stereo female adaptor to listen on both sides of your earphones.

It will sound ugly and pretty crap for the reason explained above by user16230.

Answer (score 1):

As other's have said, what you are trying to do is a bad idea.  You are using a mobile, battery powered transmitter at a fixed location and a line level receiver that is designed to be used at a fixed location for the part of the system that should really be the mobile part.

The system is only designed to send a mono feed and since the receiver most likely outputs line level signal, it isn't going to match up well with the impedance of your headphones without going through a headphone amplifier first.

A cheap wireless monitoring systems doesn't cost that much and they are specifically designed for your use case.  Don't try and hack around it.  Even a cheap wireless monitor set is going to sound way better and be far easier to use than the setup you are attempting to hack together.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the Sennheiser IEM G3 which works flawlessly with the other G3 wireless, and the IEM is purpose built for this use of headphone monitoring of the audio being sent.

Or for the same price as the G3, check out the Sony UWP-D11 which has an additional headphone port on the receiver.

Answer (score -1):

My understanding is that if you set both ends to mono then it should come through your headphones in both ears. If you set one end to stereo then you will get only one side. 
My experience has been with a D50, Roland R26, SD MM-1 and a shotgun mic.