# PA Mixer monitor - mono to stereo headphones

Tags: mixer, headphones, mono

Using the monitor output my PA Mixer, Yamaha EMX66M, to a Sterling S104H headphone amp via a TRS cable, I am only getting sound in one ear. The mixer is mono, so I assume the monitor out isn't capable of a dual-mono - or maybe my cables were just messed up (need to toy some more). Assuming this behavior is expected because it is a mono output, how can I rectify this?

Comment: Are you sure your mixer isn't stereo? It seems to have two graphic EQs (maked GEQ) on the front and two 'Master' knobs. Which output are you connecting to?

Comment: https://www.manualowl.com/m/Yamaha/EMX66M/Manual/153058 mono output needs mono jack & mono receiver or bridge. a TRS will feed only one side of a stereo amp.

Comment: @Tetsujin - worth posting that as an answer, I reckon

Comment: @RoryAlsop - had a quick attempt, not seeing any easy 'amazon' type links for a quick adaptor solution... maybe my terminology doesn't match 'consumer', but idk what else to call a bridge to mono ;)

Answer (score 3):

It's a mono output jack, so needs a mono jack, or preferably TRS with bridge, if you're going to a stereo headphone amp.

A regular TRS > TRS will arrive at the headphone amp as one side of a 'stereo' feed, so will need bridging to provide dual mono. You can buy jack converters that will do this, or with a soldering iron, connect left & right, leaving ground as is.

Ref: https://www.manualowl.com/m/Yamaha/EMX66M/Manual/153058

Additional ref - [Stereo and mono cables and jacks? What happens when you cross them?](https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/25577/stereo-and-mono-cables-and-jacks-what-happens-when-you-cross-them)

Comment: Great, that's what I was thinking. Would you mind linking such a bridge product? I am unfamiliar and don't want to buy the wrong thing haha.

Comment: I'd really be tempted to say, go to your local Maplins/Radio Shack & tell them what you need. Googling 'stereo to mono jack' doesn't guarantee it will bridge properly. Your headphone amp will have a true stereo TRS socket & I'm not certain it will bridge correctly if you insert a regular mono jack; I'm betting it would connect Right to Ground, not Left to Right.